# Volatility swaps historical data

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility

I am preparing a study about Volatility and Variance Swaps.
Does anyone know where I can found historical public data regarding this instruments?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you find any data on variance swaps? I would like to do some research, too.

Comment: Note that it seems that OP never came back to this site so I don't expect an answer from her. I would like at the others answers to get started with your collection process.

Answer (score 2):

There are no free resources that provide historical bid and ask prices for option chains. You should consider buying them from a data provider.

However, you can start accumulating data from yahoo using the getOptionChain function of the {quantmod} R package.

Comment: Option chains are not varswap or volswap prices, though of course the two are related.   Given all the arbitrary choices made in turning option chain data into a varswap price (mid-price or mid-vol, weighting, etc) it is fair to say two market participants could be quite far apart in varswap prices even with identical option chain feed data.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find any public sources. Suggest you ask a counterparty. There are also data vendors who collate var swap data, e.g. Markit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for *exact* volatility and variance swap market prices then as others have said you need to go to a data provider.

If you are satisfied with good/accurate *approximate* prices for both instruments, then the paper [It takes three to smile](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3265046) explains how to find these prices from three quoted options.